# Restrict access to webform submission nodes for anonymous

Tags: webforms

I have a webform in my drupal website. I am uploading a text and pdf file through it. Now I am displaying all the content in a list using a block which is accessible for everyone. It's working fine.

So for every submission there is of-course a node created dynamically. Like - **http://localhost/mysite/webform/upload/submissions/3**
So it can be 3, 4, 5 whatever as uploading goes on. Now i have to restrict the access of these nodes / url pattern only to admin. I have tried every thing i found in webform settings configuration. No Luck !!!

One thing i can do is add css to hide that, but i dont think its the way to do it.
So, Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What is the webform version?

Answer (score 0):

In Webform (i checked version 5.8) you can do the following.

- Go to the form in question, to the settings tab, and then the access tab
- You can click and tune "view any submissions" and set it to the "admininstrator" role
- You can also tune the area  "view own submissions"
- You can do the same thing via main permissions page (/admin/people/permissions)